# reCAPTCHA - link to the Login button

Tags: java, html, recaptcha

I have been trying to implement a reCaptcha in my little project. I added two scripts below the login validation form section, and reCaptcha is working fine, but I would like to remove a reCaptcha "Submit" button and link it to "Login" one. Can anyone help me with this?

```
</div>
        
        <div id="content">
            <form action="Validation" method="post">
            <table> 
                <tr><td>UserName: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="<%=user%>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password :</td><td><input type="text" name="password" value="<%=pass%>"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"/></td></tr>
            </table>  
        </form>

         <form method="post" onsubmit="return submitUserForm();">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My site key" data-callback="verifyCaptcha"></div>
    <div id="g-recaptcha-error"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script>
var recaptcha_response = '';
function submitUserForm() {
    if(recaptcha_response.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">This field is required.</span>';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
 
function verifyCaptcha(token) {
    recaptcha_response = token;
    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '';
}
</script>
```

I have tried a few things, but they did not work for me.

Comment: Hi, you mentioned you tried a few things, what have you tried? Can you share this with us?

Answer (score 0):

*All sorted*

```
</div>
        
        <div id="content">
<form action="Validation" method="post" onsubmit="return submitUserForm();">
    <table> 
        <tr><td>UserName: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="<%=username%>" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password :</td><td><input type="password" name="password" value="<%=password%>"/></td></tr>
        
        <tr >
            <td colspan="2">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My site key" data-callback="verifyCaptcha"></div>
            <div id="g-recaptcha-error"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"/></td></tr>
    </table>  
        
</form>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script>
var recaptcha_response = '';
function submitUserForm() {
    if(recaptcha_response.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">This field is required.</span>';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
 
function verifyCaptcha(token) {
    recaptcha_response = token;
    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-error').innerHTML = '';
}
</script>
```

Comment: call me dumb, but i don't see the `recaptcha_response` being sent anywhere to the backend (java). its an important part for [verifying the token](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). if i were an attacker to your form, i'd just use browser console and populate `recaptcha_response` with random text and your form will be submitted without any problem. Even worse, by bypassing the browser altogether, a simple http post would let form submission to pass.